# выводит неправильные значения

Tags: c++

В чем ошибка?задание вычисление функции разложения  в ряд. во
внутреннем цикле значение суммы
ТЕКСТ ЗАДАНИЯ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include<cmath>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int n)
{
    int fact = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        fact *= i;
    }

    return fact;
}

int main()
{
    int i, n;
    double x, xx, sum = 0.0, summa = 0.0, eps = 0.25;
    cin >> n;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> x;
        xx = (-1) * x * x + 1;
        sum = eps + 1;

        if (abs(sum) > eps)
        {
            sum = pow(xx, i) / factorial(i);
            summa += sum;
        }

        cout << "Значение приближенное по eps:" << ' ' << summa << ' ' <<
             endl;
        cout << "Значение без eps:" << ' ' << pow(M_E, xx) << endl;
    }
}
```

входные данные n=5 х1=-2.7 х2=-0.1 х3=2.9 х4=17.9 х5=117.0

Comment: См. дополненное решение. Только ничего хорошего у вас при последних точках не получится...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(abs(sum)>eps)
```

замените на

```
while(abs(sum)<eps)
```

с соответствующим изменением `sum` перед началом цикла, и уберите цикл `for`. Впрочем, у вас наворочено гораздо больше, чем одна ошибка. Что вы, собственно, хотите вычислять? По исходнику - вроде бы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так? Словом, дайте четкое ТЗ, тогда будет проще набросать вам нормальный код, чем исправлять это...

Ну, раз внесено исправление ТЗ...

```
const double eps = 1e-12;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int N;
    cout << "Number of trials? ";
    cin >> N;
    for(int n = 0; n < N; ++n)
    {
        cout << "Trial " << (n+1) << ". x = ";
        double x;
        cin >> x;

        cout << "x = " << x;
        x = 1.0 - x*x;
        cout << "; exp(1-x^2) = " << exp(x);


        int i = 1;

        double term = 1.0, sum = 1.0;
        while(abs(term) > eps)
        {
            sum += term *= x/i++;
        }
        cout << "; series = " << sum << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Только учтите, что реально это будет вычисляться ну, где-то при `|x|<=4`. Дальше этот метод просто не будет работать - из-за того, что члены сначала будут крепко расти, а уж потом уменьшаться, так что погрешность вычислений сведет все на нет. В лучшем случае, если поменять порядок вычислений и пытаться суммировать с учетом всех нюансов - ну, может, еще немного и получится поднять диапазон. Но ни для запрашиваемых вами 17.9, ни тем более для 117 вы ничего разумного не получите...

Comment: спасибо только что означает eps = 1e-12; ?

Comment: "Точность вычисления ε задается в программе непосредственно"

Comment: а нельзя написать eps=0,25 ?

Comment: Да хоть миллион! С какой точностью хотите - с такой и вычисляйте... Только потом не удивляйтесь результатам :)

Comment: аа понятно ,спасибо большое=)

Comment: Ну, если все понятно и вопросов больше нет - помечайте ответ птицей :)

Comment: еще  кое-что : int main( int argc, const char * argv[]) что за параметры ? они нигде не используются

Comment: Можете смело их убрать. Это параметры командной строки программы; у меня так шаблон настроен.

Comment: а зачем первоначальные значения равны term = 1.0, sum = 1.0;?

Comment: Это член при `i=0` (он же сумма, состоящая из одного этого члена).

Comment: Предваряя следующий вопрос об `sum += term *= x/i++;` Здесь 1. вычисляется новый член `term` (распишите сами отношение S_i к S_(i-1), и вы все поймете); 2. Этот член прибавляется к сумме `sum`; 3. Значение `i` увеличивается на единицу. Можно расписать так: `term = term * x/i; sum = sum + term; i = i + 1;` Но C/C++ позволяет все это записать кратко и выразительно...

Comment: а где вычисляется факториал?

Comment: А он сам по себе не нужен. Еще раз - распишите сами отношение S_i к S_(i-1), и вы все поймете.

Comment: все да я все расписал и все понял ,спасибо огромное \m/

Comment: Ну, тогда добавляйте +1 к карме :)